# Qt disable to click other windows

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Widget and a MainWindow, i created widget in mainwindow's header. When widget shows and raises, i want to disable to click other window until user close active window.

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

is not enough for me.

**Solution:** ( Dmitry Sazonov )

```
setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
```

Comment: `QWidget::setWindowModality`?

Comment: if you use `QDialog`, you can call to `QDialog::exec`. this method shows the dialog as a modal and another windows will be disabled until dialog is shown.